# Pass a variable to an abstract parent state using the ui-sref directive with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am setting up a simple angularjs app that manages groups, in which I use ui-router for nested routing.

```
var groupsApp = angular.module('groupsApp', [
    'ui.router',
]);
```

Each group has participants and a program. The page `/#/groups` shows a list with links to each group using the `ui-sref` directive:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: {{group.id}}})">{{group.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

State navigation is configured as follows:

```
groupsApp.config(
    function($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('groups', {
                url: '/groups',
                templateUrl: 'partials/groups.html'
            })
            .state('group', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/:group_id',
                templateUrl: 'partials/group.html',
            })
            .state('group.participants', {
                url: '/participants',
                templateUrl: 'partials/participants.html',
            })
            .state('group.programm', {
                url: '/programm',
                templateUrl: 'partials/program.html'
            })
    });
```

And I use the following controller:

```
var myAppControllers = angular.module('myAppControllers', []);

myAppControllers.controller('GroupController', ['$scope', 
  function ($scope) {

    $scope.groups = [
      {'id': 'group1',
       'name': 'My first group',
      {'id': 'group2',
       'name': 'My secord group',
    ];

  }]);
```

The `group` state is abstract, the `group_id` determines the url. For groups with id's group1 and group2, the possible url's are:

```
/#/group1/participants
/#/group1/program

/#/group2/participants
/#/group2/program
```

With the `ui-sref` directive I want to navigate to the participants page of a group:

```
<a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: {{group.id}}})">{{group.name}}</a>
```

Therefore I navigate to the `group.participants` state and pass along the `group_id` parameter to indicate for which group. However this is a parameter of the parent state `group`. Clicking the link results in the following url:

```
/#//participants
```

Apparently the parent class `group` does not get this parameter. Does anyone has an idea how this could be achieved?

p.s. I now realize that maybe the problem is the nesting of the angular expressions:

```
{group_id: {{group.id}}}
```

Is this allowed?

Comment: The nested expression is fine and should evaluate properly. Shouldn't the url for the group state be `/group/:group_id`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo with the possible url's for group1 and group2. I have edited that. So the url for groups is `/#/groups` the url for the participants of a group is `/#/group1/participants`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a plunker which is working and should follow your needs: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFkRNv5fj594b83Fdcs0?p=preview)

One of the changes:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <!--
      <a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: {{group.id}}})">{{group.name}}</a>
      -->
      <a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: group.id})">{{group.name}}</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

And also the snippet of the `state` definitions *(in fact the same as in the question, but running)*

the groups defintion:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('groups', {
      url: '/groups',
      template: '<ul> ' +
      '    <li ng-repeat="group in groups"> ' + 
      '     <a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: group.id})">' +
      '        {{group.name}}</a> ' +
      '   </li> ' +
      ' </ul>',
      controller:['$scope','$state',
        function ( $scope , $state){ 

          $scope.groups = [{name : "My first group" , id : "group1"}
                         , {name : "My second group", id : "group2"}];

      }],
    })
```

And here is the `group` `abstract` state. It does have access to the `$stateParams` and stores them in the scope. All child states do have access to it as well.

```
.state('group', {
    abstract: true,
     url: '/:group_id',
     template: '<div>' +
     '   <h4> group: {{group_id}} <a ui-sref="groups">back</a></h4>' +
     '   <div ui-view></div>' +
     ' </div>',
     controller:['$scope','$state','$stateParams',
       function ( $scope , $state , $stateParams){ 
         $scope.group_id = $stateParams.group_id;
         $scope.params = $stateParams;
         $scope.state = $state.current;
         $scope.showJson = function(x) { return JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 2); };
     }],
 })
```

The child states of the abastract `group`, can consume what was already prepared for them

```
 .state('group.participants', {
     url: '/participants',
     template: '<div>' +
     ' <h5>params</h5> ' +
     '   <pre>x{{showJson(params)}}</pre>' +
     ' <h5>state</h5> ' +
     '   <pre>{{showJson(state)}}</pre>' +
     ' </div>',
 })
 .state('group.programm', {
     url: '/programm',
     template: '<div>programm</div>'
 })
 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The nested expression in my html file was the cause of the problem. As suggested by Radim, changing:

```
<a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: {{group.id}}})">{{group.name}}</a>
```

to,

```
<a ui-sref="group.participants({group_id: group.id})">{{group.name}}</a>
```

resolved the issue.

Many thanks for your help Radim!

Comment: Great to see that;) Enjoy `ui-router` ... awesome tool

Comment: It certainly is. I just started to use it, and I am a great fan already.